Geometry Proximity Fade Intersect
How do you have an object fade out the closer it gets to another objects proximity? Couldn't find an answer for YEARS until now.

Here is another method sent to me by the amazing creator of the  Cell Fluids Add-On! Purely through the Shader Editor!



FINALLY. FOR YEARS I HAVE BEEN ASKING THIS QUESTION AND I FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT.
Basic Rundown:
This method involves Geometry Nodes and Shading Nodes. Essentially in the Geometry Nodes Editor of the object you want to fade out, you use fancy nodes to calculate the Geometry Proximity and then make this an attribute, so that in your material of the object you want to fade out you use the same attribute and plug it into a color ramp so that can adjust the transparency levels.
Directions:
Calculate Geometry Proximity with GeoNodes:
Open the Geometry Nodes Editor of the object you want to fade out.
Add in an Object Info Node (set to Relative) and select the mesh that will be the proximity. (This could also be a Collection Info Node).
Plug the Geometry Output into a Geometry Input of a Geometry Proximity Node and set it to Faces.
Plug the Distance into a Color Ramp Node and tweak the values.
Plug the Color Output of the Color Ramp Node into the Value Input of a Store Named Attributes Node. Change the name to Proximity. Make the options Float and Face. There is a Geometry Input Node here, make sure your initial Geometry Output.
Plug the Geometry Output of the Store Named Attributes Node into a new Group Output Node and name it Proximity.
Set Transparency in the Object Material:
Open the object material you want to fade out.
Add in an Attribute Node and type out Proximity in the name. Plug the Color Output into a Color Ramp Node.
Plug the Color Output of the Color Ramp Node into the Fac of a Mix Shader, then a Transparent BSDF into the top of a Mix Shader Node and your original Material into the bottom socket of the Mix Shader Node.
This is just what worked for me. Good luck everybody!

Add a couple of images of your Geometry and Shader nodes layout and you can get rid of most of that text!
